# php function to limit mysql query results

Tags: php, function

Hi I'm currently using the following code (1) to LIMIT the number of lines for the results to be displayed. But I want to use a different method but it is not working (2) could someone please help me with the correct syntax?

Code (1) Current.

```
function find_all_limit10() {
    global $db;
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM stock ";
    $sql .=" ORDER BY po_date DESC";
    $sql .=" LIMIT 10";
    return find_by_sql($sql);
}
```

Code (2) Desired but missing LIMIT 10 and ORDER BY

```
function find_all_limit10($table) {
    global $db;
    if (tableExists($table)) {
        return find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM {$db->escape($table)}"); 
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You can't use functions inside of curly braces. You need to break out of the string.

Comment: I'm new to this. Would you mind giving me the exact syntax including the break out?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do. In PHP you can join strings using `.` So we will append the result of the `$db->escape($table)` string to the end of the SELECT Statement.

```
function find_all_limit10($table) {
    global $db;
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM ". $db->escape($table);
    $sql .=" ORDER BY po_date DESC";
    $sql .=" LIMIT 10";
    return find_by_sql($sql);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Really appreciate. Thank you very  much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after...

```
function find_all_limit10($table) {
    global $db;
    if (tableExists($table)) {
        $data =  find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM " . $db->escape($table) ); 
        // assuming $data is an array of rows
        // keep just 10
        return array_slice($data, 0, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked nicely, just missing the ORDER BY. But worked well. Thank you very much.

Comment: give me an example of an order by column